# MKMapPointForCoordinate returning point with x and y values set to -1

Tags: ios, mapkit

I'm trying to draw an overlay with a set of Location Coordinates, but while I'm converting each coordinate to MKMapPoint the resulting point comes with the x and y values set to -1

Here's the snippet of my code

```
    idxGen = 0;
    for (idx2 = 0; idx2<[decodePoints count]; idx2++) {
        CLLocation *location = [decodePoints objectAtIndex:idx2];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = location.coordinate;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D c = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coord.latitude, coord.longitude);
        MKMapPoint point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coord);

        NSLog(@"%f, %f", c.latitude, c.longitude);

        if (idxGen == 0) {
            northEastPoint = point;
            southWestPoint = point;
        }
        else 
        {
            if (point.x > northEastPoint.x) 
                northEastPoint.x = point.x;
            if(point.y > northEastPoint.y)
                northEastPoint.y = point.y;
            if (point.x < southWestPoint.x) 
                southWestPoint.x = point.x;
            if (point.y < southWestPoint.y) 
                southWestPoint.y = point.y;
        }
        if (idxGen >= count) {
            count = count + baseCount/2;
            tempPointArr = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * (count));
            memcpy(tempPointArr, pointArr, sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * idxGen);
            free(pointArr);
            pointArr = tempPointArr;
            tempPointArr = NULL;
        }
        routeSegmentPoints[routeSegmentIndex] = point;
        pointArr[idxGen] = point;
        idxGen++;
        routeSegmentIndex++;
    }
    SLRoute *route = [SLRoute routeWithPoints:routeSegmentPoints count:[decodePoints count]];
    [directionDict setObject:route forKey:@"route"];
    free(routeSegmentPoints);

}
```

This is the log I'm geting

> 2014-10-12 15:22:37.533 Mappir[1814:200574] -99.174258, 19.466190
>   2014-10-12 15:22:37.534 Mappir[1814:200574] -99.173764, 19.465703
>   2014-10-12 15:22:37.534 Mappir[1814:200574] -99.173437, 19.465442
>   2014-10-12 15:22:37.535 Mappir[1814:200574] -99.173437, 19.465442
>   2014-10-12 15:22:37.535 Mappir[1814:200574] -99.173346, 19.465369
>   2014-10-12 15:22:37.536 Mappir[1814:200574] -99.172818, 19.464496
>   2014-10-12 15:22:37.536 Mappir[1814:200574] -99.171372, 19.462071
>   2014-10-12 15:22:37.537 Mappir[1814:200574] -99.170748, 19.460947
>   2014-10-12 15:22:37.537 Mappir[1814:200574] -99.170687, 19.460857
>   2014-10-12 15:22:37.538 Mappir[1814:200574] -99.170687, 19.460857
>   2014-10-12 15:22:37.538 Mappir[1814:200574] -99.170471, 19.460543

Comment: Where is this code?  What kind of overlay are you creating?  Did you log the coordinates that you are passing to MKMapPointForCoordinate?  On what line does it show -1 for the map point and how are you seeing that (NSLog, debugger)?

Comment: I'm trying to create a route overlay and yes, i have logged for the values of both the coordinate and the point. The coordinate value is ok as it has a valid lat, lng pair of values, bur the point returns with x and y as -1 after calling the MKMapPointForCoordinate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`idxGen` doesn't change within your loop, so if it isn't 0 to begin with it'll you'll never set `northEastPoint` to be a MKMapPoint, and if it is 0, you'll always set it to be the last MKMapPoint in `decodePoints`.

As to why the result is -1, you'd have to give some sort of hint as to what values are stored in `decodePoints`. Perhaps log the values of `coord` as you go.

Comment: idxGen is modified somewhere else within the loop, it has nothing to do with the question. As for the coords' log...

`2014-10-12 15:22:37.533 Mappir[1814:200574] -99.174258, 19.466190
2014-10-12 15:22:37.534 Mappir[1814:200574] -99.173764, 19.465703
2014-10-12 15:22:37.534 Mappir[1814:200574] -99.173437, 19.465442
2014-10-12 15:22:37.535 Mappir[1814:200574] -99.173437, 19.465442
2014-10-12 15:22:37.535 Mappir[1814:200574] -99.173346, 19.465369
2014-10-12 15:22:37.536 Mappir[1814:200574] -99.172818, 19.464496
2014-10-12 15:22:37.536 Mappir[1814:200574] -99.171372, 19.462071`

Comment: yeah…without showing your log statement in code that isn't as much use as you think. You should also show what it is that you're evaluating to get the -1 value. Update the code in your original question, preferably to show the whole loop and anything that modifies `northEastPoint`.

Comment: I just updated the code and the logs in the question.

Comment: Ah, you have a latitude of -99. That's not possible, it only goes from -190 to 90. Therefore MKMapPointForCoordinate can't create a valid MKMapPoint for you and you get -1.

Comment: You're right, man. This is a valid respnse. I had this same code working but then I had to change the JSON I get from the servr, and it stopped working. They inverted the parameters and then it was breaking all my stuff.